# How can I catch the clear button in a UITextField

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to catch a clear button method  from a UITextField somehow and then and give it  more things to do like clear annotations on a map  etc ?

On which method I need to catch to additional with the clear button ?

Thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: Have you tried adding this to your [`textFieldShouldClear`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear:) method of the `UITextFieldDelegate` delegate protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set yourself as the text field delegate and implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. If the `range` is the full range of the `textField.text` and the replacement `string` is equal to `@""` then it is a clear operation.

Note that the user manually selecting all text and hitting backspace on the keyboard will have the same result.